# How to resolve the django migration conflict?

Tags: django

There was a situation when a message appeared on the server

```
CommandError: Conflicting migrations detected; multiple leaf nodes in the migration graph: (0063_auto_20200530_1040, 0062_merge_20200527_1444 in vendors).
To fix them run 'python manage.py makemigrations --merge'
```

I followed the command, but now a new migration file has appeared during the execution

```
Created new merge migration /home/ubuntu/mat/apps/vendors/migrations/0064_merge_20200601_0807.py
```

But the local machine and github don't have this file, so every time I pull a new code from github to the server, there will be a problem with the difference in migrate.
How do I fix this correctly?

Comment: Push this file?

Comment: push back to github from server ?

Comment: Yes. Usually, I resolve this locally